# Problems with a while loop (python basis)

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm new using Python and I need a little help with this while loop:

```
List=[]
x=str(input("name: "))
y=int(input("mark: "))
List.append(x,y)
while x!="0":
    x=str(input("name: "))
    y=int(input("mark: "))
    List.append((x,y))
```

The problem of this while-loop is that, when I put '0' after 'name: ' to break the loop, the program does not break immediately: on the contrary, it asks me for y ('mark: ') and in the Output it also prints me the tuple ('0',0)

I'll try to be more clear:

```
***Expected output:***

name: Lisa

mark: 6

name: John

mark: 8

name: 0

[('Lisa',6),('John',8)]

***My actual output with my code:***

name: Lisa

mark: 6

name: John

mark: 8

name: 0

mark:0  #I put 0 because the program asks me for another int (wrong)

[('Lisa',6),('John',8),('0',0)]
```

I also tried with this code, same identical problem:

```
while True:
    if x=="0":
        break
    else:
         x=str(input("inserisci cognome: "))
         y=int(input("inserisci voto: "))
         List.append((x,y))
```

Comment: list.append() takes only one argument

Comment: You should use `List.append((x,y))` instead of `List.append(x,y)`

Comment: x=str(input("inserisci cognome: ")) should be just before if x=='0':, then it breaks loop right after enter

Comment: Check if `x` is `'0'` after user enters it and if it is, `break`.

Answer (score 1):

while loops don't end when the condition becomes false anywhere. The way that while loops work is that they check the condition and if it is true they run all the lines within the loop, then recheck the condition. You set `x` to be 0, but the other two lines will still run (asking for Y and appending to the list) before the while loop gets checked. This is a hacky solution but you can try it.

```
name_list=[]
x = ""
while x!='0':
    x=str(input("name: "))
    if x == '0':
        break
    y=int(input("mark: "))
    name_list.append((x,y))
```

Hope that helps!

P.S. it's also probably good practice to not call lists `List`

Comment: The problem with your second solution is the same, python code runs iteratively, you won't get to that if statement check until you've run the other two lines.

Comment: also this solution is trying to pass 2 parameters to list.append() function

Comment: also in your example there is no x before the while loop starts so it cant run.

Comment: @marxmacher ok, I fixed it, my bad. Only noticed the one problem on my first go around. Thanks!

Comment: now fix the double and single quote inconsistency and i will remove the down vote :)

Comment: @marxmacher sure, if it helps your OCD.

Comment: If you ever start writing code for money and work with other people then life will be much easier for you if you follow some known guidelines, like PEP8 - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 1):

You should sort it the other way around:

```py
List=[]
x=str(input("name: "))
while x!='0':
    y=int(input("mark: "))
    List.append(x,y)
    x=str(input("name: "))
```

Comment: this cant work. you are passing 2 arguments to a list.append() function

Comment: Yes, i didn't edit that part of the code, it should be ```List.append((x, y))```

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy example. I assumed you wanted to append a tuple into the list.
The while will run forever in this example unless x does not equal "0".

```
List = []

while True:
     x=str(input("inserisci cognome: "))
     if x == "0":
         break
     y=int(input("inserisci voto: "))
     List.append((x,y))
```

Comment: You need to unindent that `if` statement. Otherwise, this is the best answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

Why not input **y** after checking **x** is 0 or not?

```
List = []
x = str(input("name: "))
while x!='0':
    y = int(input("mark: "))
    List.append( (x,y) )  # Make Sure you insert only one argument in List which is a tuple (x, y)
    x = str(input("name: "))
```